# ZipTransformer compress a list of files

Tags: spring-integration

My goal is to create multiple zip files, each containing a certain number of entries. I am using an `Aggregator` for grouping files before transofrmation.

Is it possible to use a `ZipTransformer` to compress a `Message<List<File>>`?

**EDIT**:
*I am getting circular dependency exception when declaring ZipConverter as a bean. What can be a solution?*

**EDIT 2** The problem with circular dependency is solved by removing `@Bean` annotation from the `@Transformer`, and providing current ApplicationContext to `zipTransformer.setBeanFactory(appContext)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According `ZipTransformer` source code that is exactly what you have to do - send a message with `List<File>`:

```
protected Object doZipTransform(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
   ...
   if (payload instanceof Iterable<?>) {
        ...

        for (Object item : (Iterable<?>) payload) {

            final ZipEntrySource zipEntrySource = createZipEntrySource(item, lastModifiedDate, baseName + "_"
                    + counter + fileExtension, this.useFileAttributes);
            ...
        }
   }

...
private ZipEntrySource createZipEntrySource(Object item,
        Date lastModifiedDate, String zipEntryName, boolean useFileAttributes) {

    if (item instanceof File) {
        final File filePayload = (File) item;

        final String fileName = useFileAttributes ? filePayload.getName() : zipEntryName;

        if (((File) item).isDirectory()) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Zipping of directories is not supported.");
        }

        return new FileSource(fileName, filePayload);

}
```

There is a test class in the project to confirm that: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/blob/master/spring-integration-zip/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/zip/transformer/ZipTransformerTests.java

Comment: I see  that `zipTransformer.setBeanFactory()` is a required call. What is supposed to be its argument?

Comment: That is called automatically by the Spring Dependency Injection container. Only what you need to declare it as a bean. See more about the Spring Container in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#spring-core